# Український відповідник ідіоми "made my day"

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми, сленг

Вираз "[*make someone's day*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make_someone's_day)" означає:

> Зробити щось, що перетворить для іншого буденний або нудний день на такий, що запам'ятався

У нас цей вираз здебільшого дослівно калькують: "[Обама зробив мій день](http://nv.ua/ukr/world/countries/obama-zrobiv-mij-den-sotsmerezhi-pidkorjuje-video-zi-106-richnoju-amerikankoju-shcho-tantsjuje-v-bilomu-domi-98980.html)", "[Про суддю, який зробив мені день](http://hromadske.volyn.ua/pro-suddyu-yakyj-zrobyv-mij-den/)", хоча, як на мене, звучить воно кострубато.

Чи є питомі відповідники в нашій мові зі схожим смислом?

Comment: А як вам нейтральний варіант **"визначив мій день"**?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, а воно десь вживається? Бачу [всього 4 трапляння](//www.google.com/search?q=%22визначило+мій+день%22+OR+%22визначити+мій+день%22), з них лише 1 — точно в тому сенсі, 2 — точно не в тому і ще 1 — незрозуміло.

Comment: @Sasha, думаю, ви погодитеся що, вочевидь, hardly possible підібрати єдино правильний і вже широко вживаний варіант для таких нових вкраплень з інших мов. Ба більше, в оригіналі цей вираз теж має кілька значень, і автора запитання, наскільки я зрозуміла, цікавить не головне , а саме у відповідному контексті, в якому почав уживатися не так давно і переважно в молодіжному середовищі. Як на мене, **"визначити день"** - найбільш нейтральний варіант, на відміну від **"аж світ вгору піднявся"**, чи **"приколоти"**, або **"замолодити"**. Хоча розумію,що це виключно моє суб'єктивне відчуття.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, ну, чесно: «аж світ вгору піднявся» мені зрозуміло, що значить. (Хоча, «Обама підняв мені світ угору» — вже не факт.) «Приколов», «відколов», «відмочив» — теж (хоч, може, це й росіянізми). («Замолодив» я до сьогодні не знав.) «Визначив мій день» — мені незрозуміло. Але це моє суб'єктивне сприйняття. Можете спробувати оформити як відповідь, принамні [одне трапляння](//ok.ru/ukrplaycast/topic/66050497926429) є.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, ну, чому ж, цікавий варіант. Я б запостив, врешті й «пруф» є. Хоча, як знаєте, звісно.

Comment: Є ще російський фразеологізм «скрасить день», може чимось допоможе в пошуку.

Comment: Фраза _визначити день_, поки не можу привести приклади, мені здається, надає дещо інший відтинок, як би мовити, щось визначальне: дещо серйозне, ба, навіть неминуче. Наприклад: _Смерть визначила мій день_. Отже, _визначати день_ — день, який якось впливає на життя, погляд чи щось кшталт цього.

Comment: @Follower, якому відповідає англійський «[brighten up the day](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brighten+up+the+day)».

Answer (score 12):

Найближчий за змістом фразеологізм, який зміг знайти:

> [аж світ вгору піднявся](http://ycilka.net/slovnyk_fraz_view.php?id=18) - у кого-небудь поліпшився настрій, моральний стан

Comment: Можна ж ще сказати _приколов_, _замолодив_. ))

Comment: А яке значення слова _приколоти_? [Словник сленгу](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Pyrkalo_Svitlana/Pershyi_slovnyk_ukrainskoho_molodizhnoho_slenhu.pdf) каже, що _приколотися_ - означає захопитися чимось.

Comment: Будь ласка, сформулюйте остаточний варіянт. "*Обама підняв мені світ вгору*"?

Comment: Ні, краще _"Обама підняв мій світ угору"_.

Comment: @user2513149 - _Приколоти_ – це насмішити, підняти настрій, «Обама мене сьогодні приколов», _прикольний_ – класний, смішний.

Comment: @YellowSky, взагалі в мене «світ угору піднявся» більше асоціюється зі *щастям*, а «замолодив» і «приколов» — з *гумором*. «Зробив мій день» теж спочатку з гумором асоціювалося, але, подивившись приклади в питанні, бачу, що вони якраз про щастя. Але було б добре, якби Ви окрему відповідь про «[замолодив](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53399/374512.html)» і «приколов» написали. (Бо це теж значення «make someone's day», хоч приклади наведені й не про це значення.)

Answer (score 10):

Волинська журналістка Ірина Качан пише про рідне місто: "Побувати там вранці — [*втіха на весь день*](http://www.volynpost.com/news/18549-misto-iake-ia-lyublyu-luck-prokydaietsia-chastyna-3)".

Answer (score 5):

Пропоную від себе ще один варіант:

> Настрій на весь день

*Obama has made my day.* - *Обама зробив мені настрій на весь день.*

*You made my day.* - Просто: *Настрій на весь день.*

Answer (score 2):

- Задавати
- [Влаштувати](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%22)
- Завдавати — якщо негативне значення

[Борис Рогоза](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), газета [”Хрещатик”](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/111.htm):

> Слово **завдавати** означає “спричиняти, чинити комусь щось неприємне” й сполучається, як правило, з іменниками негативного “забарвлення”: **завдавати болю**, **втрат**, **жалю**, **клопоту**, **мороки**, **мук**, **неприємності**, **поразки**, **прикрості**, **скорботи**, **смутку**, **страху**, **суму**, **тортур**, **туги**, **удару**, **шкоди** і т. ін. Не слід плутати його із задавати, основне значення якого — “пропонувати, давати щось для виконання, вирішення або відповіді; *влаштовувати щось*”. Отже, **задавати жару**, **завдання**, **задачу**, **перцю**, **прочухана**, **тон**, **урок**, **хропака**, **чосу**.

Comment: Остаточно — "*Обама задав мій день*"?

Comment: Мені подобається!